# Oracle right Index to avoid full table scan

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query that yields around 10M records and it is doing a full table scan impacting our upstream applications. Can you please suggest an optimal index on following columns that would avoid a full table scan. Or if there is a better way to write this to avoid a full table scan.

```
select * 
from qt.ORDERS r 
where r.id = (
    select max(cr.id) 
    from qt.ORDERS cr 
    where cr.id = r.id)
  AND r.idtype<>3)
```

Comment: can youshow a query plan and the create table also read up on index hint https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10752/hintsref.htm

Comment: Parenthesis don't look balanced.

Comment: If `cr.id = r.id` then `max(cr.id)` will always be equal to `r.id`. That means all the rows of the table will be selected. A full table scan is the best option in this case.

Comment: Do u think  a functional based index on max(id) will aid any help here??

Comment: The whole subquery is useless, you can rewrite your query as this: select * from qt.orders r where r.idtype<>3. And the full table scan is probably the best way to return the rows, especially with a result in the millions of rows.